# loop through array and return jsx - react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop

I am trying to map through an array and return jsx however I'm using Typescript and so `.map` only returns functions (not jsx). **How can I loop through the array and return some jsx for each array element in React?**

I already have
`return (<div>{array.map(this.function)}</div>)` so I'm returning a function on each array element but I would like to return both jsx and a function from map. I've tried this `{array.map(() => {return this.function && <p>text</p>})}` but it's just returning either the jsx or the function.

What I want to achieve: When I map through the array, I want to run a function on each array element as well as return a paragraph `<p></p>` on each element so that I can display some text next to the output of the function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: map returns whatever the callback function returns, so if the map returns a function, then you are calling it wrong, perhaps try calling the callback twice? `array.map((...args) => this.function(...args)())`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `I would like to display some jsx next to the rendered function`

Comment: Can you show the return of `this.function`? It is also important to make sure you are using HOC correctly to get a function using this.

Comment: Ah yes I see thanks, I returned some jsx but I need to return jsx and a function. Is it possible to return both jsx and a function from `.map`? I tried using `&&` but it's returning either the jsx or the function?  @KrzysztofKrzeszewski

Comment: i feel like this may be a case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you provide us with more details on what you are trying to achieve, instead of how you tried to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add the proper key:

```jsx
{array.map((el) => (
    <React.Fragment key={}>
        {this.function(el)}
        <p>text</p>
    </React.Fragment>
 ))}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! The problem was that I wasn't actually calling the function, I added `()` and it worked. @HaJa